# Reading resources from jar file with NETBEANS

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am trying to read resources from java class.
I have read a lot of information on the net, but not found a good one that solve my problem.
I wand to set icons dynamically fron png files.
On netbeans 8.2/Windows 7 the solution used is working
But when I create a jar for the program, with the same icon path I got a null value for the url.

### ----------

```
      pathToImage = "/images2/letter-E-icon.png";                 // OK in netbeans, KO in jar<br/>
  ImageIcon img;<br/>
  putConsole("pathToImage= "+pathToImage);<br/>

  URL url = this.getClass().getResource(pathToImage);<br/>
  putConsole("url= "+url);<br/>
  img = new ImageIcon(url); <br/>
  JmenuItem_ENC.setIcon(img);<br/>
```

---

Below is the source structure and after the jar structure
I suspect a problem with netbeans.
Can you help me?
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuKLp.jpg)

*** VARIOUS STRUCTURES ******
1) Source files
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1
              build
             3ÿ883 build.xml
              dist
              nbproject
              src
              test
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\build
                68 built-jar.properties
              classes
              depcache
              empty
              generated-sources
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\build\classes
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\build\classes\enc_dec
             7ÿ688 AES.class
             3ÿ872 APP_CNST.class
             2ÿ243 CryptAES.class
               502 CryptoException.class
               726 DisplayFile$1.class
             8ÿ001 DisplayFile.class
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\build\classes\images2
BUILD all icons .....
               756 add_entry-icon.png
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\build\classes\resources
               323 admin_properties.properties
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist
              lib
           238ÿ859 MyCrypt_RC1.jar
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist\lib
            35ÿ843 jgoodies-common.jar
           122ÿ504 jgoodies-forms.jar
           481ÿ534 log4j-1.2.16.jar
           348ÿ143 MyLib.jar
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\nbproject
            80ÿ592 build-impl.xml
               475 genfiles.properties
              private
             3ÿ210 project.properties
               565 project.xml
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\src
              enc_dec
              images2
              resources
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\src\enc_dec
...... all java code ..........
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\src\images2
SRC all icons
               756 add_entry-icon.png
             1ÿ211 xopen_all.png
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\src\resources
other resources from properties
               323 admin_properties.properties
=======================================================================
2) Jar file hierarchy
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist\zip
              enc_dec
              images2
              META-INF
              resources
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist\jar\enc_dec
.... All classes .....
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist\jar\images2
.... All icons .....

               756 add_entry-icon.png
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist\jar\META-INF
               243 MANIFEST.MF
\dev\java\MyCrypt_RC1\dist\jar\resources
               323 admin_properties.properties

Answer (score 0):

I have been busy to solve this problem.
I restarted all freshly with a new project and I manage to find the correct
solution.

---

In the following figure, I indicate what is working for the directory structure:

Thanks for the help
[This is the directory structure (clik)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJZ0s.png)